# Problem while trying to write elements from mysql into text file

Tags: python, string-formatting

```
file = open("BasicTextFile.txt", "w")

query = "SELECT name, amount, description FROM customers_payments7777 GROUP BY customer_VAT"
mycursor.execute(query)
for row in mycursor:
    file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{row[1]}\t\t{row[2]}")
    file.write("\n")

file.close()

os.system("notepad.exe BasicTextFile.txt")
```

This is my code. It is getting some information from a table in MySQL and then it is writing it into a file. But the result I am getting is something like:

```
James   50.00            Hello
Nick            25.00
```

The result I want to get is something like:

```
James    50.00    Hello
Nick     25.00
```

Comment: stop using `\t`, and start using string-formatting, see chapter 7.1.1 of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: can you give an example with string-formatting using my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change line: `file.write(f"{row[0]}\t{row[1]}\t\t{row[2]}")`

to: `file.write(f"{row[0]:10} {row[1]:7.2f} {row[2]:10}")`

The first and third column wil have a length of 10 characters (`:10`), and the second column will be shown with max 7 characters, with 2 after the decimal `.`. (`:7.2f`).

If your text (or numbers) are larger then the space provided, the output will not be aligned, so you should choose the column widths to fit the longest text.